# How to insert dynamically images in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am developing a WinForms App which can generate a report of my college students.

I am using Crystal Reports but I don't know how to retrieve student photos from the file system.

Student photos are stored on the file system and use this naming convention:

```
C:\Id Maker\"Clgid".jpg
```

Where `Clgid` is a value stored in a database.

As an example, my `Clgid` is `AAAAAAA` which links to my photo on the file system as `C:\Id Maker\AAAAAAA.jpg`

I am struggling with how I can look up the database value of `Clgid` and then retrieve the photo from the file system so I can display it in my Crystal Report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, add a graphic as a placeholder into your report where you want it to display. Then, right-click the graphic -> 'Format Graphic' -> 'Picture' tab -> Add a formula under 'Graphic Location' that builds your path string. Something like `'C:\Id Maker\' + {table.Clgid} + '.jpg'` should work.

Comment: @DineshGehlot It's not working? Does any pictures load? All I can suggest if it is not working is to verify the file names and paths are correct and that the paths are local to where the report is run.

Comment: @Ryan This doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using a Crystal Report "viewer" that I can scroll through my individual reports with First/Next/Previous/Last button. The only image that loads whether I pass it with the other information on the report or not, is the default image. I tried using the database method as you suggested, but it just hangs when it attempts to load the image, eventually (sometimes) loads, and then still has the default image. Any ideas?

Comment: @Keith It sounds like CR can't find the image/path (see my comment above). If you have a small number of images, you may also try embedding each image you want to display in the .rpt itself. You can stack them and then selectively suppress them so only one displays for each row.

Comment: "...and that the paths are local to where the report is run" -- What do you mean? I can't give it a direct path like: "C\Test\123.jpg" if the CR isn't ran from there?