# Multiple images in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to achieve the following,
I need to generate report for multiple companies in a common format. I need to do it in a single report. The only issue exist with report header images. In the header of the report, I need to display the company header. So for Company1, I will dispaly Image1. For Company2, I will display Image2 etc. What is the best methode to achieve this. Putting N number of image control and set visibility is a right choice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically insert an image by its file path like this:
[how to insert dynamic images in crystal reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079118/how-to-insert-dynamically-image-in-crystal-report/9081102#9081102).

Alternatively, you could do it the way you suggest by adding n different images and dynamically suppress them based on values in the report. Doing it this way will require you stack the images, each with its own suppression formula which isn't as clean of a solution in my opinion. It'll also cause the report file size to be larger if that matters to you at all.