# displaying images on crystalreport

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

This is my code,i want display images that stored in sql to crystal reports,please someone help me :)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    string connectionstring = null;
                    SqlConnection conn;
                    connectionstring="Server=AJITHBABU\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=temprorary;User ID=sa;Password=2604";
                        conn=new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
                        byte[] img = null;
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgloc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                        img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
                        k = "INSERT INTO temprorary4(id,img)values('" + textBox1.Text + "',@img)";
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd = new SqlCommand(k, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img",img));
                    int x=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString() +"record(s) saved");


                }
```

Comment: Possibly related question [how to insert dynamically image in crystal report](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9079118/4519059) ;).

Comment: Possibly related question [Insert image to crystal reports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23227513/4519059) ;).

Comment: No..it is not working